# Recyclerview dataset update proper method

Tags: android, memory, android-recyclerview

to update data of recyclerview i have tried three method

1. `notifydatasetchanged()`
2. `swapadapter()`
3. updating `List<>` and assigning same Adapter.

but when i update data in each method **memory allocation** (to app) keep **increasing** by range of(0.25 to 0.50)MB how to solve it?

My adapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
public static int Sub;

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


    TextView personName;
    ImageView personPhoto;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Sub = getLayoutPosition();
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }}

List<Person> persons;
RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}
public void swap(List<Person>persons){
    persons.clear();
    persons.add(new Person("htfg", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));//0
    persons.add(new Person("fhe", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));//0
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}
}

Comment: Post your RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 0):

Use `adapter.notifyItemChanged (itemPosition)` or any other .notifyItem...() native adapter methods.